# Java - Keep whitespaces after saving XML

Tags: java, xml, dom, whitespace

I have XML files where i have to remove just 1 attribute.

After saving the edited XML the whitespaces are deleted, which i need! (see image)

When do i lose the whitespaces?

When i parse the xml in a doc? 
Or when i transform back to an xml?

I already use much Output Propertys from the Java Transformer like:

```
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, encoding);
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
    transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.DOCTYPE_PUBLIC, "yes");
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.CDATA_SECTION_ELEMENTS, "RequestMessage Code");
```

to avoid other formating problems.

Is there a way to keep the whitespace?

Thank you

EDIT 1: XSL I use to avoid an alphabetical order

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xslt" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" xalan:indent-amount="2"/>

    <!--Identity transformation (see http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#copying).-->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@Item"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@Name"/>            
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@Include"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@Variant"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@Authorization"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@Alias"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@Source"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@Field"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@DgMemberName"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@DgGroupName"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@Target"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@Host"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@DataGroup"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[image: Here u see the Diff between the two XML files]

Comment: Why do you need bunch of spaces between attributes ? I doubt that the transformer has any option for such a strange thing .

Comment: Its a requirement. With the space it's easier to read..

Comment: Please try to increase indent-amount to some higher value.

Comment: XML is there to store data, not to present data. If you need a cute presentation, consider throwing an XSL transformation in .

Comment: @SachinGupta When I increase the value, space is added from the left side

Comment: There are no XML parsers/generators what will retain spaces between attributes. Only way for that to happen, is for you to read and update the XML text yourself. Highly discouraged.

Comment: use non-xml way to remove the attribute (text replacement) - your original intention is not feasible to treat it (and keep it) xml and at the same time pose restrictions that are non-xml (arbitrary whitespace)

Comment: @Berger i already use an XSL to avoid that the attributes are saved in an alphabetical order

Comment: @T. Leutner : if you can afford it, you may try to add some "padding" attribute to your XML elements.

Comment: @Berger but will I be able to see the "padding" in the XML? When i search for padding in XSL i end up with PDF stuff

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer to your question is that it can't be done using any readily-available XML serializer.

I sympathise with the requirement because I've got XML files formatted like that too. But I think it's a sufficiently rare use case that if you want to tackle it, you'll need to write your own serializer.